# Какие дополнительные данные можно вставить в CSV файл, кроме «sep=*», которые другие программы могут интерпретировать, как метаданные?

Tags: csv

Создаю CSV файл со статистикой, чтобы потом он открывался в Excel. Какие ещё указания можно добавить в файл, которые Excel будет интерпретировать, как метаданные при табличном отображении. Если это зависит не от CSV, а от Excel, то где их можно посмотреть?
Пример таких данных: «sep=;» в начале файла.

Comment: Формат CSV в принципе не предусматривает никаких метаданных, даже понятия такого применительно к этому формату - не существует. Если какая-то программа интерпретирует какие-то данные в CSV как метаданные (например, интерпретирует первую строку не как данные, а как имена полей) - это её внутреннее дело.

Comment: Тут вы можете узнать про метаданные csv. https://www.w3.org/TR/tabular-data-model/#embedded-metadata

Цвета и тому подобное Excel не позволяет. А так Akina прав.